# Rakefile causes RSpec to run tests twice

Tags: rspec, rake

I have a weird issues with rake running RSpec.  RSpec by itself works fine, but when run via rake using this Rakefile:

```
require 'rubocop/rake_task'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

RuboCop::RakeTask.new(:cop)
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)

task default: [:cop, :spec]
```

it generates output like this:

> Failures:
>
> 1) member of public accesses bike docking station unable to release as none available 
>      Failure/Error: expect { docking_station.release_bike }.to raise_error 'No Bikes Available'
>        expected Exception with "No Bikes Available" but nothing was raised
>      # /Users/me/Projects/boris-bikes/spec/feature/public_bike_access_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in '
>
> 2) member of public accesses bike docking station unable to release as none available 
>      Failure/Error: expect { docking_station.release_bike }.to raise_error 'No Bikes Available'
>        expected Exception with "No Bikes Available" but nothing was raised
>      # ./spec/feature/public_bike_access_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in '
>
> Finished in 0.01419 seconds (files took 0.36303 seconds to load)
>   10 examples, 2 failures
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec /Users/me/Projects/boris-bikes/spec/feature/public_bike_access_spec.rb:10 # member of public accesses bike docking station unable to release as none available 
>   rspec ./spec/feature/public_bike_access_spec.rb:10 # member of public accesses bike docking station unable to release as none available
>
> /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby -I/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-support-3.2.1/lib:/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/exe/rspec --pattern spec/**{,/*/**}/*_spec.rb failed

it seems to be finding the same spec file twice in the same location;

Users/me/Projects/boris-bikes/spec/feature/public_bike_access_spec.rb:10

AND

./spec/feature/public_bike_access_spec.rb:10

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Anything fix it? I'm experiencing similar behavior.

Comment: still no - another colleague experienced it too on another machine - but didn't get a close look at it - again it was only with the rake task, not the raw rspec - I think we need to submit a bug report to whoever maintains the RSpec RakeTask - I guess that's just the basic rspec folks ...

Answer (score 0):

Rspec adds itself to default. You want to remove it first with clear and then re-add it:

```
task(:default).clear.enhance [:cop, :spec]
```

Comment: thanks @dankohn - unfortunately that doesn't seem to help.  The original Rakefile does work perfectly well on other machines.  It's just this one machine that seems to have this problem which makes me think it is somehow related to symbolic links on the underlying file system - rspec runs fine though, i.e. just one test.  Am wondering if RSpec::Core::RakeTask somehow adds the RSpec search paths in a different way to running rspec from the command line ...